# Why does 50 Ω termination result in less noise than 1 MΩ termination on the scope reading?

Tags: noise, oscilloscope

Regarding the following section from the Keysight document ["Making Your Best Power Integrity Measurements"](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5992-0493EN.pdf):

[image: Quoted text from "tip 1" in Keysight document "Making Your Best Power Integrity Measurements"]

It says that using 50 Ω termination we will see less noise on the scope compared to 1 MΩ.

Can this be explained by modeling what is meant here as an electrical circuit? I'm trying to understand why lower resistance causes less noise on the scope screen.

Comment: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/powerhouse/archive/2016/07/27/how-you-measure-your-ripple-can-make-you-or-break-you also talks about a 50 Ohms while doing a accurate mesurement of noise

Comment: The noise floor of 10 pF capacitor, regardless of the parallel resistor, is 20 microvolts RMS, or about 120 uVPP. So I have doubts of the green trace's parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first thing to consider is the Johnson noise of the resistor which cannot be eliminated. The higher the resistance the greater the noise. Reducing bandwidth will also reduce Johnson noise. So if your scope has bandwidth settings, and if you don't need high bandwidth for your signal, you can get cleaner results using the reduced bandwidth modes.

The second thing to consider is noise which couples in to the oscilloscope, particularly if it couples through the probe wiring arrangement by way of a magnetic field. The time-varying magnetic field will induce a current in the probe. The termination resistance inside the oscilloscope will convert that current to a voltage. If the termination resistor is 50 Ohms, that will lead to a much smaller voltage than if it is 1M Ohm.

In general, lower impedance termination is more resistant to noise. This is a very important concept when you encounter situations where noise immunity is required. Usually any noise coupling path will have some series resistance or fundamental power limiting just by its nature. So the lower your termination resistance, the lower the voltage due to noise coupling. Sometimes a 20 pF capacitor on a digital input can make the difference between a flaky and totally unreliable piece of junk and a rock solid product.

Often if I need to put the oscilloscope on a shunt resistor, I will use the 50 Ohm termination feature of the oscilloscope. This greatly reduces noise, and since the shunt resistance is much less than 50 Ohms (for the shunts I deal with) there is no worry of excessive current flowing into the oscilloscope, even if the shunt current may be high.

[image]

This image was formally assigned to the public domain by its creator (not me). Retrieved here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/JohnsonNoiseEquivalentCircuits.svg)

Answer (score 7):

Because it takes a lot more induced noise current to produce the same noise voltage across 50 Ohms compared to 1 megaOhm. The tradeoff is that it is more difficult to drive.

A brick and a piece of paper: Which one is more resistant against disturbances and undesired movement in a breeze?  Which is easier to move when you actually want to move it? You can't have it both ways. Same idea.

Comment: Thanks but I dont get the analogy. I need a simple circuit model with maybe a noise source if needed.

Comment: @panicattack To the system, there is no difference between desired and undesired change. Something that is difficult to be disturbed by noise will also be difficult to be disturbed by you. Likewise, something easy for you to manipulate will also be easy for noise to manipulate.

Comment: @panicattack From V=IR, if I is constant then a larger R gives a larger V.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Why do you model the noise as constant current source?

Comment: @panicattack I am no expert on the matter, but the material containing the electrons will be at the same temperature, so the thermal noise generated by the electrons is the same, and the flow of electrons is current. Bear in mind that I could be completely wrong about the mechanism.

Comment: Even if the noise model is not a constant current source, there is likely a series resistance in the model. One way or another, the power available for a noise source coupling into your measurement system will be limited. The lower your termination resistance, the lower the noise voltage. This is just the voltage divider rule. To say that the ESR of the noise source is zero is to (ultimately) say that the available noise power is unlimited which flies in the face of reality (conservation of energy and whatnot).

Answer (score 7):

Because [Johnson-Nyquist noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise).  Resistors generate thermal noise, with a noise power that's proportional to the absolute temperature.  A higher-valued resistor will then generate more noise *voltage*, with the voltage proportional to \$\sqrt{R}\$.

Setting your O-scope up as a \$1\mathrm{M}\Omega\$ instrument gets you the noise from that \$1\mathrm{M}\Omega\$ resistor; if you're measuring some super low-impedance node like you'd find in a power supply, you gain absolutely no accuracy from the high impedance.  So you measure at \$50\Omega\$, and get less noise.

Comment: Interesting, so it is due to the Johnson noise. But if you in practice measure a power supply’s noise on scope do you really terminate with 50 Ohm resistance?

Comment: Normal scope probes have a built in 1MΩ resistance (I'm pretty sure some or all is actually built into the cable).  So using a normal cable puts that in series with the source.  Fancy scopes let you switch in a 50Ω terminator so you can plug a 50Ω cable into it, and if you're using a cheaper scope you can get an in-line 50Ω terminator.

Comment: To the OP: There are two main considerations when using 50 Ohm mode. First, will the resulting current fry the oscilloscope input? You don't want to measure 120V line voltage in 50 Ohm mode, obviously. Second, will the thing you are measuring tolerate a 50 Ohm load? Measuring a signal with a 50 Ohm termination is equivalnet to placing a 50 Ohm resistor directly across the thing you are measuring. Sometimes that is OK and sometimes it is not OK because the 50 Ohms will totally change the very voltage you are trying to measure.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use 50 ohms, a larger value would also have less noise.
Lets take sqrt (500MHz) = 22.360 and divide the 74uV by this value.

The scope noise input is on the order of 3.3 nano volts, whereas the 50 ohm resistor has a spot noise of about 0.9nV therefore, we could raise the termination by a factor of almost 10x for only a 3dB rise.  That is, a 500 ohm termination on that Keysight scope would be about 100uV of noise.

The key issue is what is the spot noise of the instrument. It is 3.3nV in 50 ohm mode, and around 11nV in 1Meg mode, which is an equivalent of 7.8K ohms.  We can never get below those spot figures, even if we use a shorted input. (Ignoring current noise for the present. I'm kind of surprised a scope like the unit quoted could have inputs that quiet. Maybe it goes with the 50k price tag.)